# Map sequence of functions to a sequence

Tags: function, dictionary, clojure, sequence

How could I map each function in a sequence of functions to its corresponding value in a sequence of values ?:

```
(map '(sequence of functions) '(sequence of values))
```

the nth function in the function sequence should be applied to the nth value in the value sequence. sorry if i'm not very clear.

for example, say `(def fns '(#(+ 1 %) #(- 1 %)) )`

then `(map (some-clever-function-of fns) '(0 0))` would produce (1 -1) because `#(+ 1 %)` was mapped to the 1st 0 and `#(- 1 %)` to the 2nd.

Answer (score 10):

- Pass `map` more than one sequence of arguments, and it'll do exactly what you want.  `(map f seq1 seq2)` expects `f` to be a function that takes two arguments; `map` will pas the first element of `seq1` and the first element of `seq2` to `f`, then the second element of each, etc.  As soon as any seq of arguments runs out, `map` stops, so this works with infinite sequences as well.
- Consider using vectors instead of quoted lists.  Vectors stand out as "data" rather than "code", and you don't have to quote them.
- Your example functions don't do what you want; both return 1.  I suspect you meant `#(+ % 1)` and `#(- % 1)`.  Both of these are in `clojure.core`, called `inc` and `dec` respectively.

So:

```
user> (map (fn [f x] (f x)) 
           [inc dec] 
           [0 0])
(1 -1)
```

Or:

```
user> (map #(%1 %2) [inc dec] [0 0])
(1 -1)
```

Comment: Or use "apply" e.g. (map apply [inc dec] [[0] [0]]) => (1,-1)  ?  Makes the data seq kind of ugly though.

Answer (score 1):

I usually define an `invoke` function that acts like `apply` but without the list-collapsing:

```
(defn invoke [f & args]
  (apply f args))

(map invoke [+ -] [1 2] [3 4])
(4 -2) ; 1 + 3, 2 - 4
```